# Postfix - Send mail by Odoo ERP from catchall@

Tags: odoo, postfix-mta, smtpd

i have a big problem.

Please help me (i am noob).

I use Odoo ERP, and this system need privileges to send e-mail from catchall@mydomain.com, on behalf of any e-mail address in the domain zone (like john@mydomain.com). Now my postfix server say:

```
postfix/smtps/smtpd[1]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from 1.1.1.1.a.domain.com[1.1.1.1]: 553 5.7.1 <bounce@mydomain.com>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user catchall@mydomain.com; from=<bounce@mydomain.com> to=<xy@mydomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<eupp133.odoo.com>
```

In my main.cf file have:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch, permit_sasl_authenticated, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit

smtpd_relay_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023, permit
```

Thank You!

I tried to found solution in Odoo docs, and asked my server owner (this is a rented server). The solution is not widespread in my country, so he also don't know.

Comment: You should configure the settings of an extermal mail server (Brevo, Mailchimp, ...) by using the "outgoing mail server" feature in Settings>Technical

Comment: Which Odoo version?

Comment: @CZoellner Odoo 17.

Comment: @Ahrimann In this method, DKIM and most e-mail servers reject e-mail.

Comment: DKIM can be configured properly in Brevo and Mailchimp...

Comment: Have you looked into the official documentation especially [this part](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/17.0/applications/general/email_communication/email_servers.html#use-a-default-from-email-address)?

Comment: @CZoellner in this section i not found relevant information.    


BUT    
I found solution, so now works: in my postfix config i need to modify main.cf    


`mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 34.34.157.xxx (this ip is my Odoo.sh ip)    
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unlisted_sender, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch, reject_unauthenticated_sender_login_mismatch, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit`

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, so now works: in my postfix config i need to modify main.cf

`mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 34.34.157.xxx (this ip is my Odoo.sh ip)`

`smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unlisted_sender, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch, reject_unauthenticated_sender_login_mismatch, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit`